# WakefulBroadcastReceiver onReceive called twice

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, wear-os, android-broadcastreceiver

I need to periodically read data from Google Fit via the Fitness API for a watch face development.

I'm using AlarmManager every POLL_INTERVAL_MS interval to broadcast an Intent to a WakefulBroadcastReceiver which starts an IntentService executing the data read task.

This is the code I'm using.

In the manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".FitDataAlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

In watch face engine onCreate

```
FitDataAlarmReceiver mFitDataAlarmReceiver = new FitDataAlarmReceiver();    
mFitDataAlarmReceiver.setAlarm(MyApp.this);
```

In FitDataAlarmReceiver class

```
public class FitDataAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    private static final long FIT_DATA_POLL_INTERVAL_MS = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(60);

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, FitDataAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123456, intent, 0);
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, POLL_INTERVAL_MS, POLL_INTERVAL_MS, alarmIntent);

    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        if (alarmMgr!= null) {
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, FitDataManagerService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }

}
```

In my IntentService I then obtain a new wake lock, start the data read stuff and then release it together with the receiver one (by calling completeWakefulIntent method).

cancelAlarm method is of course called in the watch face onDestroy.

```
mFitDataAlarmReceiver.cancelAlarm(MyApp.this);
```

It works. But, what's happening is that the onReceive in the FitDataAlarmReceiver class is triggered twice very quickly without even respecting the first POLL_INTERVAL_MS parameter of the setRepeating method call.

It takes a couple of - literally - false alarms before the receiver starts receiving correctly timed invocations. I don't know why.

SetAlarm is called only once in the onCreate method of the watch face engine. 
However the onCreate method of the watch face engine itself is also (inexplicably) being called two times(!).

I've filtered out the second onCreate call by using a simple semaphore, and it is now called only once.
Nevertheless, onReceive is still called twice.
Only if I use the debugger and place a breakpoint in the onReceive, it is called just once.

These are my questions:

Why is the onCreate method in the watch face Engine class called two times?

And, even if I manage to filter out one call, why is the receiver onReceive being called twice?

Comment: Is your watch face engine's `onDestroy` called between the calls to `onCreate`? I'm guessing that (for some reason) the system creates one instance of your face, quickly destroys it, then creates the second "real" instance.

Comment: It was indedd called two times. I changed from an `IntentService` to a `Service`, did a general code cleanup and now it is not happening anymore. but i don't exactly know why. Thanks anyway, @String